# My program unexpectedly finishes when I call return in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this recursive function which traverses a binary tree and returns the value of the node when it gets to a node that is leaf but my program unexpectedly finishes at the return call. 
Here is my code:

```
string decodeFile(int cha, ibitstream& input, HuffmanNode* encodingTree, HuffmanNode*& root, string& result) {
  if(root->isLeaf()) {
    char value = root->character;
    string temp(1,value);
    cout << temp << endl;
    return temp;
  } else {
    if(cha == 0) root = root->zero;
    if(cha == 1) root = root->one;
    decodeFile(input.readBit(), input, encodingTree, root, result);
  }
}
```

so I console out to check what is happening and at that point it returns a value but when i go to the main function to cout it returns nothing.

Comment: It's surprising how common this error is. I'm not sure what it is about recursion that makes newbies think `return` is unnecessary.

Comment: This code should not compile. Did you forget to switch on “treat warnings as errors”?

Comment: i have never used that before. Why should it not compile?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig This code is required to compile, by the standard, unless the compiler can prove that regardless of the input, it will always be called at least once with `!root->isLeaf()` (and that `input.readBit()` returns).

Comment: @otch92 Chris is saying that you should always pay attention to compiler warnings because they often indicate actual errors (as in this case) or at least bad coding style. The best way to do this is to turn on the 'treat warnings as errors' option. This way any code with warnings will not compile so you are forced to correct them.

Comment: @JamesKanze This is one of the things where I’ll happily use a compiler switch saying “don’t let me do everything the standard allows.” *Most* code with warnings *should not*, in my opinion, compile. Because it saves me time and headaches if it does not.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig I'd agree _if_ the warning didn't give a lot of false positives.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're not returning value from the recursive call to the caller:

```
string decodeFile(int cha, ibitstream& input, HuffmanNode* encodingTree, HuffmanNode*& root, string& result) {
if(root->isLeaf()) {
    char value = root->character;
    string temp(1,value);
    cout << temp << endl;
    return temp;
} else {
    if(cha == 0) root = root->zero;
    if(cha == 1) root = root->one;
    // do calculation and return result!
    return decodeFile(input.readBit(), input, encodingTree, root, result);
}
```

> its a string type so i return the value as a string temp

Imagine that you're entering your code from main function and that you're going into `else` branch in the first call of `decodeFile` which will call `decodeFile` again:

```
main -> decodeFile -> decodeFile
```

Now, the second `decodeFile` is returning value with `return temp`, but the first `decodeFile` is not returning anything to the `main` function (as it is exiting after call to `decodeFile`):

```
main (NO RETURN)  decodeFile <- decodeFile
```

In order to avoid these kind of errors, listen Riot and add additional warning flags to your compiler.

Comment: its a string type so i return the value as a string temp

Answer (score 0):

Your function is failing to `return` anything in the `else` portion of the branch.

If you're using gcc, you can get your compiler to warn you about such cases using the `-Wreturn-type` or `-Wall` options.